# BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for android on Load

Tags: android, android-volley

Having trouble on `VolleyRequest` getting always error response when loading it `onCreate`. I want to do is when the `fragment` loads. but when I try it, the `Logcat` gives me an error 400. on this `Java class`, i have another function that has sending data to `API`. I just copied my code :). here is the code that getting a error response.

```
 String url = "MYLINK.com";

    try {
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());

        StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Successful send pending data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        String qu = ("update tickets set is_send = '1' where ticket_tick_no = '" + ticket_tick_no_delayed + "'");
                        sqldb.execSQL(qu);
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error Response here", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.e("------", String.valueOf(error.networkResponse.statusCode));
            }
        }
        ) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();

                params.put("control_no", trip_no_delayed);
                params.put("trip_no", ticket_control_no_delayed);
                params.put("ticket_no", ticket_tick_no_delayed);
                params.put("ticket_datetime", ticket_datetime_delayed);
                params.put("ticket_kmfrom", ticket_kmfrom_delayed);
                params.put("ticket_kmto", ticket_kmto_delayed);
                params.put("ticket_placefrom", ticket_placefrom_delayed);
                params.put("ticket_placeto", ticket_placeto_delayed);
                params.put("amount", ticket_amount_delayed);
                params.put("discount", ticket_discount_delayed);
                params.put("trans_type", transaction_type_delayed);
                params.put("passenger_type", passenger_type_delayed);
                params.put("lat", ticket_lat_delayed);
                params.put("long", ticket_long_delayed);
                params.put("device_serial", device_serial_delayed);

                return params;
            }
        };
        queue.add(postRequest);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: already add android.permission.INTERNET? and request the permission at  runtime?

Comment: yes. i also use that same function (but different variable) on button pressed

Comment: have you checked the response on `postman` or any other tools

Comment: yes it returns success. i don't know why it return error